# error installing valgrind on mac

Tags: macos, valgrind

i am installing valgrind on my mac 10.6.8, i go the valgrind directory and run the following commands

```
>> ./autogen-sh
>> ./configure
```

its working fine but when i run

```
>> make
```

its giving the error alot of errors the last part of error is

```
ld: symbol(s) not found
make[3]: *** [memcheck-amd64-darwin] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

can anyone give the solution for it i searched alot but did not find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Homebrew:

```
brew install valgrind
```

*Important:* Valgrind is only stable in OS X Mavericks and older versions.

Comment: what is the purpose of using brew i am new to mac can't get it, what is the problem with the previous one i have followed all the instruction from their official document

Comment: [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is a package manager. It automates installing/uninstalling/updating packages. There is no problem installing it manually as you wanted, but you would need to manage this updating/uninstalling part manually if you do it like that. Macports is another example of a package manager for OSX, and it has the same purpose of Macports.

Comment: you mean both are same if i do it using homebrew or manual , so what is the problem using manual i mean is there some package issue or system misconfiguration issue i can't find any thing about that

Comment: I didn't say both are the same. Many packages are not really tested by its developers in OSX, so some of them might not build/run out-of-the box like you are trying to do with valgrind. Package managers, like homebrew and macports, usually add/change/fix settings on the packages when necessary to make them build/run without problems. For example, I believe the problem you are having has to do with environment variables, that must be fixed in both package managers suggested. Long story short: use package managers to avoid headaches with things you don't want to spend time with.

Comment: Also, as @trojanfoe said, consider using XCode Instruments instead of valgrind in OSX. Instruments have a nice user interface, and can give you better assistance to track problems with your code than valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't install any package from source these days; instead install [Macports](http://macports.org) and simply do:

```
$ sudo port install valgrind
```

You should also consider using *Instruments* instead of *valgrind*, as it's very much Linux-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem as the original poster when I tried to run the manual install of the program after downloading it from http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html
I am using the most current OS, El Capitan. The way I solved my issue was by going to http://brew.sh and downloading that by pasting it into my terminal. Then I ran `brew install valgrind`
It did work and I now have valgrind on my mac. A very useful line to use with Valgrind is

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --num-callers=20 --track-fds=yes ./"your executable"
```