# How to install valgrind on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, homebrew, valgrind

I have recently purchased an M1 MacBook Pro and I am having issues installing valgrind on macOS Big Sur.
What I have tried so far is:

- brew install valgrind which pops the error (brew is updated)

`Error: invalid attribute for formula 'valgrind': version (nil)`

- edited head as indicated [here](https://www.gungorbudak.com/blog/2018/04/28/how-to-install-valgrind-on-macos-high-sierra/)
- download manually from [GitHub](https://github.com/LouisBrunner/valgrind-macos/tree/feature/macos_11pp) following all indications listed but I get

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/homeuser/Library/Logs/Homebrew/valgrind/03.make:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach/i386/thread_status.h:254:9: error: unknown type name '_STRUCT_X86_DEBUG_STATE64'
typedef _STRUCT_X86_DEBUG_STATE64 x86_debug_state64_t;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach/i386/thread_status.h:260:9: error: unknown type name '_STRUCT_X86_PAGEIN_STATE'
typedef _STRUCT_X86_PAGEIN_STATE x86_pagein_state_t;
        ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/mach/i386/thread_status.h:266:9: error: unknown type name '_STRUCT_X86_INSTRUCTION_STATE'
typedef _STRUCT_X86_INSTRUCTION_STATE x86_instruction_state_t;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [fixup_macho_loadcmds] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

- looked into this older [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667759/error-installing-valgrind-on-mac) that used to work

Unfortunately none of the methods work so I would really appreciate a solve to this problem as I need to use valgrind on a daily basis for university homework.

Comment: Looking [here](https://www.valgrind.org/info/platforms.html), it looks like valgrind does not support Apple silicon at all.

Comment: I was afraid someone might say that.
Thanks!

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931093/valgrind-and-macos-big-sur

Answer (score 7):

Definitive answer. See the `configure.ac` autoconf file for the exact details. Starting from line 5021 [which may change in future versions, obviously] there is a switch on the kernel versions.

The last version of macOS officially supported by Valgrind was 10.13 on Intel. Neither macOS 11/12 (any architecture) nor ARM are supported.

Getting Valgrind to work on macOS 11/12 ARM hardware would require

- filling in all of the gaps from 10.13 to 11/12
- ARM assembly code for low level functions like syscalls

There is Linux ARM support, so the second point might not be so difficult. I don't have an ARM based mac, so I'm not vounteering for the moment.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, so thank you -- but saying "Definitive answer" comes off as a bit overconfident. In my view, "definitive" answers tend to be direct quotes from the source project's documentation. It really helps to include hyperlinks to project changelogs and/or other documentation. From your profile, it looks like you contribute to Valgrind (thanks!). I think saying that gives more credibility to your answer than saying it is "definitive".

Comment: I maintain the FreeBSD Valgrind port and try to keep en eye out for Solaris and macOS. I'll add a reference to the relevant file.